# LexikJWTBundle does not recognize valid configuration keys

Tags: symfony, jwt, symfony-3.3, lexikjwtauthbundle

I get the following error using lexikjwtauthenticationBundle

```
Unrecognized options "secret_key, public_key" under "lexik_jwt_authentication"
```

My configuration is similar to

```
lexik_jwt_authentication:
secret_key:       '%jwt_private_key_path%' # required for token creation
public_key:       '%jwt_public_key_path%'  # required for token verification
pass_phrase:      '%jwt_key_pass_phrase%'  # required for token creation
token_ttl:        '%jwt_token_ttl%'
```

And parameters.yml has the following parameters

```
jwt_private_key_path: '%kernel.root_dir%/config/jwt/private.pem'
jwt_public_key_path: '%kernel.root_dir%/config/jwt/public.pem'
jwt_key_pass_phrase: '*******'
jwt_token_ttl: 3600
```

Answer (score 3):

I was was able to find the answer to the question.

```
lexik_jwt_authentication:
  secret_key:       '%jwt_private_key_path%' # required for token creation
  public_key:       '%jwt_public_key_path%'  # required for token verification
  pass_phrase:      '%jwt_key_pass_phrase%'  # required for token creation
  token_ttl:        '%jwt_token_ttl%'
```

The correct configuration is:

```
lexik_jwt_authentication:
  private_key_path: '%jwt_private_key_path%' # required for token creation
  public_key_path: '%jwt_public_key_path%'  # required for token verification
  pass_phrase: '%jwt_key_pass_phrase%'  # required for token creation
  token_ttl: '%jwt_token_ttl%'
```

Comment: The documentation isn't wrong, you are looking at the master branch documentation. [They've made changes for version 2.5](https://github.com/lexik/LexikJWTAuthenticationBundle/commit/a6a77189cd9400a4483129bf683955d67e8d8711#diff-74ed4025fc55c5e8d1361816bbb96fe3)